# Are these sets compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces

I've some problems concerning this question:

> Are the following sets compact in $C_{[0, 1]}$ where $ d(x(t), y(t))=\sup_{[0,1]}|x(t)-y(t)|$:
>   $${\{x(t) \mid x(t)=e^{t-a}, a>0\}},~~{ \{ x(t) \mid t^{\alpha}(1-t)^{\alpha}, \alpha>1 \}}$$

Comment: this is unsolvable wihtout knowing what topology you use on $C[0,1]$

Comment: I think that neither of these is even close: I guess $t\mapsto e^t$ is in the closure of the first set of functions and $t\mapsto t(1-t)$ is in the closure of the second set.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: As pointed out by saz, these sets are not closed as the first does not contain $e^t$ and the second does not contain $t(1-t)$. If the inequalities are replaced by equalities however, the sets are closed and the following shows that they are compact.

Recall the [Arzela-Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem), which states that a subset of $C_{[a,b]}$ is relatively compact iff it is equicontinuous and pointwise bounded. For the first set, note that for any $t,t'\in [0,1]$ we have 
$$|e^{t-a}-e^{t'-a}|=e^{-a}|e^{t}-e^{t'}|<|e^{t}-e^{t'}|$$
so since $e^t$ is continuous it follows that the set of functions $\{e^{t-a}:a>0\}$ is equicontinuous. Since this set is clearly pointwise bounded by $e$, it is relatively compact. For the second set, note that 
$$\frac{d}{dt}t^\alpha(1-t)^\alpha=\alpha t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^\alpha+\alpha t^\alpha(1-t)^{\alpha-1}$$
and if we can show this is uniformly bounded in $\alpha$, say by $M$, then we would have
$$|t^\alpha(1-t)^\alpha-{t'}^\alpha(1-t')^\alpha| =\left|\int_t^{t'}\frac{d}{dx}x^\alpha(1-x)^\alpha\mathrm{d}x\right|\leq M|t-t'|$$
and so we can choose $\delta=\epsilon/M$ to show equicontinuity. Recalling that $t^\alpha(1-t)^\alpha$ achieves its maximum at $t=1/2$ (which can be proven a number of ways), we have that
$$\begin{align}
\alpha t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^\alpha+\alpha t^\alpha(1-t)^{\alpha-1} &\leq \alpha t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{\alpha-1}+\alpha t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{\alpha-1}\\
&\leq \alpha (1/2)^{\alpha-1}(1/2)^{\alpha-1}+\alpha (1/2)^{\alpha-1}(1/2)^{\alpha-1}\\
&\leq \frac{\alpha}{2^{2\alpha-1}}\leq \frac{1}{2}\\
\end{align}$$
as desired. Since the second set is also pointwise bounded (by $1$) it is relatively compact as well.

Comment: The sets are relatively compact (as you proved, by Arzela-Ascoli), but they are not closed, as far as I can see.

Comment: @saz Whoops, very good point.

Comment: The function $x \mapsto 0$ should also be contained in the first set (to be closed), because $e^{t-a} \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ as $a \to \infty$.

Comment: Looks good.  Arzela-Ascoli is pretty much the one and only way to answer questions about compactness in $C(K)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are in a normed vector space: recall that compact implies closed + bounded.

Both sets are easily seen to be bounded. But they fail to be closed.

1) What happens if you consider the sequence $(x_n(t)=e^{t-\frac{1}{n}})$? You can show it converges uniformly to $x(t)=e^t$. And this does not belong to your set.

2) Now take the sequence $(x_n(t)=t^{n}(1-t)^n)$ and show it converges uniformly to $0$ as $n$ tends to $+\infty$ (recall that the sup of $t(1-t)$ over $[0,1]$ is attained at $1/2$). Now does $0$ belong to your set?